# MS-MPI application failed on more than one node

Tags: mpi, distributed, ms-mpi

I have two virtual boxes with windows 7. Their IPs are 10.0.0.20 and 10.0.0.22. From one virtual box I can ping the other one.

On both boxes I open an `smpd` connection:

```
smpd -p 8677
```

On both box I can see that port 8677 is listening. From one box, using `telnet`, I am able to connect the other one on port 8677. I also disabled the firewall and I don't have any antivirus.
Then I try to launch my application on 10.0.0.20:

```
mpiexec /port 8677 /gmachinefile host.txt myapp.exe
```

It works when `host.txt` is filled with

```
10.0.0.20
```

or

```
10.0.0.22
```

But when `host.txt` is composed of the two lines:

```
10.0.0.20
10.0.0.22
```

I get this error:

```
[01:1952] ERROR: unable to read the cmd header on the pmi server context, Other MPI error, error stack:
[01:1952] ERROR: connection to the pmi client broken, closing.
[01:1952] ERROR: unable to read the cmd header on the pmi server context, Other MPI error, error stack:
[01:1952] ERROR: connection to the pmi client broken, closing.
```

All the commands were launched with administrator privileges.

Comment: Are you sure your MPI implementation is Open MPI? The error messages are very much MPICH-like. MS-MPI maybe?

Comment: @HristoIliev you are right I use MS-MPI